# Angular Js Directive to Convert Input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi Guys I want to write a angular directive which encodes the input text to html.
So that critical characters are converted. For example ö -> &ouml
I have found [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) nice library, which I want to use.

My problem is I want to have this convertation only in my model. The user shouldn't see anything from this.

For now I have tried this way. But this doesn't do what I want. I'm new to angular and don't get comfortable with directives. 
Maybe you can help me.

```
angular.module('schwimmfestivalAngApp')
    .directive('encodedInput', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, ctrl, he) {

                element.bind('onblur',
                    function () {
                        ctrl.$modelValue = he.encode(ctrl.$viewValue, {
                            'useNamedReferences': true
                        });
                    }
                )
                ;

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: The link function receives it parameters in a set order. namely: link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn). You seem to have this a bit mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robert for his hints. I think I have figured it out now.

For me it works but not seems to be the perfect way.

This is for now how my directive looks for now.

```
.directive('encodedInput', function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function () {
          element.html($window.he.decode(ngModel.$modelValue || ''));
        };

        var inputString = '';

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function () {

          //Check wether the string has changed. So the & will not be extra encoded.
          if (inputString != ngModel.$viewValue) {//Combined without logging
            console.log(length);
            length = inputString.length;
            ngModel.$setViewValue($window.he.encode(ngModel.$viewValue, {
              'useNamedReferences': true
            }));
          }
          inputString = ngModel.$viewValue;
        });
        function read(string) {

        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a beginner's task as you need to have a bit more experience with Angular to make it work as expected.

Manipulating data between view and model in an Angular directive has two parts. One that does conversion from **model to view** and the other that does conversion from **view to model**. Basically you should manipulate data in both directions, so your view displays something while your model holds a *manipulated* value that satisfies your requirements.

### Model ⇒ View

You should implement `$render` function to aid this part:

```
ngModelController.$render = function() {
    ...
}
```

### View ⇒ Model

This part may implement several things. The most important thing in your scenario is probably calling `$setViewValue` function

```
element.on("blur", function(evt) {
    ngModelController.$setViewValue(...);
});
```

Naming may be a bit misleading here as we want data model value to change and not view model value, but read this excerpt directly from docs:

> When `$setViewValue` is called, the new value will be staged for committing through the `$parsers` and `$validators` pipelines. If there are no special `ngModelOptions` specified then the staged value sent directly for processing, finally to be applied to `$modelValue` and then the expression specified in the `ng-model` attribute. Lastly, all the registered change listeners, in the `$viewChangeListeners` list, are called.

But there're also directive parsers that can manipulate your view value before it gets committed to the model.

```
ngModelController.$parsers.push(customParser);

function customParser(value) {
    return /* some value */;
}
```

### Documentation details

Make sure you thoroughly read the [ngModelController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

### Important note

Make sure you implement several other points mentioned in this documentation by only adding console logs so you can get a grasp of directive execution cycle.

Comment: First: Thank you for this good explanation. This seems to be a lot of hard work. Is it simpler to convert the input and save it to an other variable?

Comment: Depends on use. If this directive is a one off, than maybe yes, but I'd argue that this is not too complicated. It's just convention one needs to follow. Many things in Angular may be a bit more convoluted, but they're there for a reason.
If you have several directives that would require similar functionality but different manipulation, you could however create a common directive but add additional parameters that would point to your specific manipulator functions.

Comment: I create this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8y10Lg9t/ but I don't get it to work. There is a little error that always added &amp to my string. Maybe someone get the fiddle to work with angular. Than I could try to show up the error.